# Why don't framework generic interface member need to declare themselves as new?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface for which I would like to create a generic with respect to the return type of a member.

So if the non generic interface is:

```
interface IViewHolder{
  IView View {get;}
}
```

and I want

```
interface IViewHolder<TView> : IViewHolder {
 where TView : class, IView
  TView View {get;}
}
```

such that I can use an `IViewHolder<T>` whereever an IViewHolder is required, I have to use the new keyword for the View member in the generic or it wont compile.

Since this seems "not right" I looked into how MS do it in the framework using reflector.

So for `IEnumerable<T>` they do:

```
[TypeDependency("System.SZArrayHelper"), __DynamicallyInvokable]
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

No new keyword required. So what's their secret.

Comment: Reflector does not generate faithful C# when decompiling CIL. If you copy the code generated by Reflector you'll see the same errors.

Comment: *Since this seems "not right"* => To me it seems perfectly right. What is it exactly that seems not right to you?

Comment: The thing that makes it "won't compile" is the `{` in the wrong place; the message "'IViewHolder<TView>.View' hides inherited member 'IViewHolder.View'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended." is a *warning* - it doesn't stop the compilation; of course, I fully endorse having the warnings-as-errors switch enabled : warnings should not be ignored.

Comment: btw, if you download the framework *source* (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) - I suspect you'll find it *does* use `new`

Comment: @MarcGravell Ahah, yes I have that option enabled and thanks for the reference to source that was about to be my next "Google".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this seems "not right" I looked into how MS do it in the framework using reflector.

At the IL level, those two things are identical; and indeed it will compile to the same IL with and without the `new` - so reflector *is kinda right*. ***The only thing*** that `new` does here is to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing here - don't add a warning" - specifically:

> Warning {x} hides inherited member {y}. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

It doesn't change the IL output. It would be *nice* if reflector went to the trouble of checking for a prior declaration, and added the `new` to make it obvious - but that is a nice-to-have only.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the error message from the compiler ?

I guess it's only a warning and it doesn't prevent you from compiling.

Comment: Almost certainly "IViewHolder<TView>.View' hides inherited member 'IViewHolder.View'"

Comment: Yes you are right, as per Marcs comments I misread the warning as an error due to compile options.